# How to transform an R! data.frame into a list of key/values with purrr or apply

Tags: r, purrr

Newbie here...
Wondering what is the best way to solve this

I have a data.frame like this that I read from a csv file

```
data <- data.frame(
  V1=c("name1","name2","name3","name4"),
  V2=c("id11","id21","id31","id41"),
  V3=c("id12","","","id42"),
  V4=c("id13","","","")
)
```

and I would like the following result

```
result <- c(
"id11"="name1",
"id12"="name1",
"id13"="name1",
"id21"="name2",
"id31"="name3",
"id41"="name4",
"id42"="name4")
```

I am wondering if the simplest solution is to do an apply (but what function) or should I look at purrr instead (and if so what function would help me ? )

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row-wise `apply`. Remove all the empty values from the row. Repeat the first value, based on `length` of non-empty values and assign names.

```
unlist(apply(data, 1, function(x) {
        name <- x[-1][x[-1] != '']
        setNames(rep(x[1], length(name)), name)
}))

#  id11    id12    id13    id21    id31    id41    id42 
#"name1" "name1" "name1" "name2" "name3" "name4" "name4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` / `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-V1) %>% 
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = V1) %>% 
  fill(id11:id42, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  distinct()
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 7
  id11  id12  id13  id21  id31  id41  id42 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 name1 name1 name1 name2 name3 name4 name4
```